# Notification from web app (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, html, angularjs, notifications

I'm developing a web app that shows a counter, and when the counter comes down to 0 I want to notify the user(The counter is on a server, so there won't be a problem with reloading the page). 
If the user is on a computer, I'm using a popup for the notification, but if the user is on an Android device, I would like the notification to be shown even if the browser isn't open.(I'm using AngularJS if that would be any help)

Is there a way to do this? I rather not build a special Android app.

Thanks.
//G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid no, there is no way to do that. When any android application is not active is... not active, frozen. The browser is not a service, so as far as I know it won't process anything while in background. Even it's possible the OS close the browser if it needs more memory than is available.

Comment: Using html5 I've successfully been able to play sound that continues even if I leave the browser, so something must be going on in the browser still?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I think it works only because it started when the browser was on foreground, and it delegated it to a player instance. Try to reproduce it with a delayed playing (using a timer or something like that), loading the page and then leaving the browser just before the sound is played. If it still works, my answer is clearly wrong.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I guess I have to make it into an app anyways.